# IntelliJ live template, annotated expression

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

In Intellij live templates, there is a function 'annotated("annotation qname")' (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-template-variables.html). How is the function used? What is the function for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This macro returns all methods/fields/classes annotated with a specified qualified name. It can be useful when creating live templates for a particular framework, where in some place you only expect names of members that are annotated in a special way.

Some predefined live templates in RESTFul Web Services and Web Services groups are using this macro.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to create a field with a statement live template? (apply live template in constructor, automatically declare a field)